# Difference between function call methods

Tags: java

So I just have a quick question on the difference between the two function call methods, as in:

```
example.function()
```

vs

```
function(example)
```

Comment: The second one could also be an unqualified instance method invocation, @Michael. In addition to what Michael said, another thing is static imports of method names that can give the impression that they're invoked on nothing, which is an illusion

Comment: @ernest_k Yep, didn't cotton on to that immediately but you're right

Answer (score 1):

`function(example)` means you call a method from the same class and pass parameter `example` to it

`example.function()` that means you call a method with no parameters from the object `example` or you call a static method from the class `example`

Comment: The first case could also be a statically imported static method. Less likely, but possible

Comment: you are right it can be from static import

Answer (score 0):

**example.function()**
here you have an object 'example' which has a method 'function' and it is calling it.

**function(example)**
here the function is called by the object of the class this code is written in (let's call it myClass), so myClass object is calling method 'function' and passing it a different object 'example'.

Note: I've made some assumptions such as you are not using a static method to simplify things.